# Facebook Page Live Comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I came across from this article. I would like to get it done for the live video from facebook pages.

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments/`

1. I tried to get User_access_token.
2. And I changed it to long_lived_access_token, it was successful

But when I tried to change it to Page_Access_token at this endpoint,

`https://graph.facebook.com/100077648863435?fields=access_token&access_token=###`

it showed

`{    "error": {       "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '100077648863435' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",       "type": "GraphMethodException",       "code": 100,       "error_subcode": 33,       "fbtrace_id": "AJvCSZWtB4T3eiPFbSXm_mE"    } }`

I am lost with facebook's complex permission problems. Could you please help me to get the result. Thank you.

Comment: You need `pages_show_list` permission, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-access-tokens-of-pages-you-manage